# Enantiomers and Flipping chiral centres

Tags: chirality

[image]

Hello,

Normally, it seems like enantiomers have inverted R/S configuration at every chiral centre. However, in the pair below which are clearly enantiomers (note the methyl and benzyl groups are going in and out of page) as mirror image of one is superimposable on the other, the configuration of the carbon in the main cycle attached to the nitrogen seem to have the same stereoconfiguration in both structures.

I suspect this has to do with the "prochiral" / meso nature of the molecule without the extra groups on the nitrogen, but have never heard of such exceptions.

Comment: These are diastereomers, not enantiomers. Incidentally, neither molecule is chiral. Both are meso. Even with the groups on the nitrogen.